# Read fasta file into a matrix or vector for MolecularEntropy function in R

Tags: r, sequence, bioinformatics, entropy, dna-sequence

I am fairly new to R so please excuse my very basic question.
I want to use the MolecularEntropy function : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/HDMD/versions/1.2/topics/MolecularEntropy

I tried to used different read fasta functions from different package such as ape or seqinr. But none worked with the MolecularEntropy function.

Here is an example of my fasta file:

```
>sequence_1
ACCTGC--A
>sequence_2
ACC-GCTTA
>sequence_3
ACCTGCTTG
```

The fasta reading function I have tried give no error for the MolecularEntropy function, but just wrong results.

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bioconductor package Biostrings has a function, `readDNAStringSet` to read in fasta files.

```
seqs <- Biostrings::readDNAStringSet("seqfile.fasta")

> seqs
DNAStringSet object of length 3:
    width seq                                               names               
[1]     9 ACCTGC--A                                         sequence_1
[2]     9 ACC-GCTTA                                         sequence_2
[3]     9 ACCTGCTTG                                         sequence_3
```

The documentation for the MolecularEntropy function says that it can accept a vector of sequences.
You can convert the above biostrings object to a named vector using `as.character`.

```
seqs <- as.character(seqs)

> seqs
 sequence_1  sequence_2  sequence_3 
"ACCTGC--A" "ACC-GCTTA" "ACCTGCTTG"
```

The documentation doesn't make it clear what the function expects for gaps.
You can replace the gaps with whatever you need using the `str_replace_all` function from stringr. Although this function is vectorized, it removes the names of the sequences from the vector. You can get around it by using `map_chr` from purrr to iterate over the vector.

```
seqs <- purrr::map_chr(seqs, stringr::str_replace_all, "-", " ")

> seqs
 sequence_1  sequence_2  sequence_3 
"ACCTGC  A" "ACC GCTTA" "ACCTGCTTG"
```

If this still causes problems reply with a comment and I can edit the post with potential fixes.

Comment: nice answer.. OP apparently needs it for a MolecularEntropy() function so i honestly don't it works you convert the above to as a matrix,

Comment: Also, stringr::str_replace_all or gsub() works on a vector. you don't need the purrr part

Comment: I mentioned it in the answer, but the stringr function removes the names from a named vector. Since performance is probably not an issue I got around it by using map, but I suppose you could just save the names to a variable and add them back later too. I'm curious whether someone knows a better way to keep the names.